# Failed to read data from a webpage using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to read data from a website www.nseindia.com using R. So below is my code which is failing -

```
> readLines("https://www.nseindia.com")
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://www.nseindia.com'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  URL 'https://www.nseindia.com/': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
```

However when I ping this website, I get response -

```
~# ping -c 4 www.nseindia.com
PING www.nseindia.com (23.8.5.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a23-8-5-63.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.8.5.63): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from a23-8-5-63.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.8.5.63): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from a23-8-5-63.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.8.5.63): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from a23-8-5-63.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.8.5.63): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=20.3 ms
```

Can someone help me to understand why R is failing to get information? Below is my session information -

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What data are you trying to read? How do you want to handle the results from `readLines(url)`?

Comment: I dont have specific choice of data now. I wonder why readLines fails to generate any return

Comment: Look at the docs for `readLines`: it doesn't take a URL. For the first argument, it says "a connection object or a character string." If it's a string, it will try to open that file. Your URL doesn't point to a file

Comment: I get return when I pass some other website - readLines('https://www.yahoo.com')

Comment: Yes, but that return is just HTML. There is no sensible way to work with that, use an appropriate tool for the job. Take a look at the **rvest**-package.